# alert showing false even the class exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

My below code seems ok, but I am trying to figure out why my alert is showing as false:

```
$.each(result, function(i,items) {
    alert($(this).parent().closest("#associated_order_chosen .chosen-drop ul").hasClass('chosen-results'));
    $(this).parent().find("#associated_order_chosen ul.chosen-results").append("<li id=\"items" + items.orderID + "\" class=\"active-result\" style=\"\"> " + items.orderunique + " </li>");
    //$select.append($("<option />").val(items.orderID).text(items.orderunique));
  });   
});
```

I tried using jQuery's `find()`, but every time it is returning me false. Am I doing something wrong? Please let me know.

`#associated_order_chosen` is the main div

**Update #1**

here is the HTML Code

```
<div class="controls">
    <select data-rel="chosen" data-placeholder="Please choose one" id="associated_order" class="passitem" style="width: 200px; display: none;" name="associated_order">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 200px;" title="" id="associated_order_chosen"><a tabindex="-1" class="chosen-single chosen-default"><span>Please choose one</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div><ul class="chosen-results"></ul></div></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Simplify the strings with using `'` inside `"` so you dont have to escape.

Comment: Without seeing your HTML it's hard to say, but if jQuery is telling you that the closest `<ul>` element that matches that selector doesn't have the class you're looking for, it's an almost guarantee that it really doesn't.

Comment: Put the result of your jQuery selector in a `var` and use the debugger console to call `.hasClass('chosen-results')` manually -- what I'm trying to say is that your `alert` line-of-code is a compound statement and you can make it easier on yourself by breaking it down into a series of simpler lines of code rather than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a contextual issue in your code. `this` in your code refers to the `items` argument(*ie. the current element in iteration*) not to a DOM Element. You should cache the `this` object outside the context of the `each` callback and use the cached value instead.

```
var $e = $(this);
$.each(result, function(i,items) {
    if ($e...) {
      // ...
    }  
});
```

Comment: i can create fiddle, but i do not know how to add json